# Can I use any class T as an allocator type as long as std::allocator_traits<T> is specialized?

Tags: c++, memory-management, standards, type-traits, allocator

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator, one class that can be used as an allocator type must meet many requirements. However, I cannot find the same requirements specified by the C++ standard. The standard only requires the allocator type must not be a non-class type. (see n3797 20.7.8.1)

If I have an empty class `Alloc` and a fully specialized `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>`, can I use `Alloc` as follows:

```
#include <vector>

struct Alloc {};

template<>
std::allocator_traits<Alloc>
{
    // full of definitions as per the requirements for std::allocator_traits<T>
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int, Alloc> coll;
    coll.push_back(8);
}
```

Comment: You can do it (mostly; you'd still have to supply `operator ==` etc.), but I don't see what you gain from it since you'd have to reimplement everything in the specialization rather than rely on the defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are going to use the allocator with STL containers (or code that adheres to the same conventions) you can define your allocator by just specialising `std::allocator_traits` for your class (for which it then just suffices to be defined; thinking of it, I think you might even hijack an existing non-allocator class for this purpose), since calls to your allocator will not be made directly, but through the `std::allocator_traits` specialisation.

Doing so seems to defeat the purpose of that class template however, since by defining that specilisation your are loosing all the defaults that the template has put in place, so you have to redefine everything, which is not easier than defining everything in your `Alloc` class directly. Specifically, 17.6.4.2.1 appears to make it undefined behavior to just specialise individual member functions like `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::allocate`, which must of course be defined.

The intended use is clearly to not specilialise `std::allocator_traits` at all, but just define those members of `Alloc` for which no defaults are provided (essentially `value_type`, `allocate` and `deallocate`; at the end of 17.6.3.5 there is an example struct `SimpleAllocator` that provides a minimal working interface), or for which you want to override the defaults (`std::allocator_traits` is set up to use any defined members with preference over its defaults).

As a personal matter, I would advise to normally always override the typedefs `propagate_on_container_move_assignment` and `propagate_on_container_swap` (but not their `copy_assignment` relative) from their default `false_type` state to `true_type`. Since container class templates cannot allow a non-equivalent allocator instance to be associated with existing memory (which would ultimately cause it to be deallocated incorrectly), they must be prepared to abandon move semantics and reallocate everything in case (the relevant one of) the two mentioned types are `false_type` *and* allocator instances are found to be unequal. It might be that the compiler is smart enough to detect that for your (stateless) allocator type instances can *never* compare unequal, and treat the above "be prepared" complication as dead code. However this dead code treatment this is easier to detect and more certain to happen if that type is `true_type`, and will then also apply for statefull allocators (allowing propagation). Stated differently, I think those two defaults are just chosen wrong.